# "innerText" sometimes contains more newlines than the user has pressed enters

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a [PicoBlaze simulator](https://flatassembler.github.io/PicoBlaze/PicoBlaze.html) in JavaScript into which the user enters the assembly code. I've tried to make an interface which displays the line numbers in the assembly code that the user enters and highlights the assembly code syntactically. However, the line numbering doesn't work correctly in some cases. If you click into the `div` with `contenteditable` that the user is supposed to type the assembly code in (called `assemblyCode`), and you press enter two times, it will claim there are four lines of code, even though there are just three of them. The JavaScript which controls the `div` left to it that displays the lines of code (called `lineNumbers`) is this:

```js
      function setUpLineNumbers() {
        const assemblyCode = document.getElementById("assemblyCode").innerText;
        const numberOfLines = Math.max(
          (assemblyCode.match(/\n/g) || []).length,
          1
        );
        let lineNumbersHTML = "";
        for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfLines; i++)
          lineNumbersHTML += i + ".<br/>";
        document.getElementById("lineNumbers").innerHTML = lineNumbersHTML;
      }
```

Can you figure out what is going on there?

Comment: When you press enter, it adds two `\n`, one at the current spot and one at the end of the content. `setUpLineNumbers()` is working correctly.

Comment: @Ouroborus, I don't think that's what's going on, press the enter more than two times, it's almost as if it adds two new lines for every enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the structure of the code panel is one `<div>` per line and some of the `<div>` contents can end with `<br>`. `.innerText` converts this to a string such that each `<div>` generates a `\n` and each `<br>` also generates a `\n`.

Rather than trying to count the number of `\n`, count the number of `<div>`.

Change your function to:

```js
function setUpLineNumbers() {
 const assemblyCode = document.getElementById("assemblyCode");
 const numberOfLines = assembly.childNodes.length;
 let lineNumbersHTML = "";
 for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfLines; i++)
   lineNumbersHTML += i + ".<br/>";
 document.getElementById("lineNumbers").innerHTML = lineNumbersHTML;
}
```

Comment: Will this work correctly when you highlight the assembly code syntactically?

Comment: It probably would have as syntax highlighting adds spans which would have been children of the divs. But, it looks like changes have been made since yesterday and now no divs are generated. You'd now have to count just `<br>` elements instead. `const numberOfLines = assemblyCode.getElementsByTagName('BR').length;` (Or use your original code as, without block elements, only `<br>` should be generating `\n`.)